# Redis unique increment

Tags: redis, unique, increment

I am trying to implement a scoring system on redis. I have no experience with it what-so-ever.

What my app should be doing is increasing a value ONLY if the user has not already voted, so I was thinking of something like this:

```
INCR voteme
```

but only if this is has not been increased already, so wanted to do the following:

```
SET voteme:voterip 1
```

so then i would count the elements. Problem is I think this is not doable in redis, and have to think of another approach.

Any ideas?

---

EXTRA question:

I want to make this data persistent by writing the resulting count (e.g: 24) to the corresponding user, in mongodb. Some pseudo code would be of great help

Answer (score 1):

I would not store a counter but directly a set containing all the users who have already voted.

Let's suppose a vote is organized for user 1. Each time, a user X vote for user 1, you can execute:

```
 SADD user:1:votes X
```

The number of votes for user 1 can be easily retrieved:

```
 SCARD user:1:votes
```

Now if you need to keep this count in sync with another store, you can execute (still supposing user X votes for user 1):

```
 MULTI
 SADD users:1:votes X
 SCARD user:1:votes
 EXEC
```

The trick is the SADD command returns the number of items effectively added to the set. If the item already exists, it returns 0. So it is quite easy to run this multi/exec block, check the result of SADD, get the cardinality of the set (number of votes), and push the cardinality to another store only if the set has been altered by the transaction.

This way, you keep the counter up-to-date in your persistent store (in real time), while filtering useless voting events.